# Android Programming, Display Certain word upon user entering Word

Tags: android, string, text

Ok so what i want to do is, make my app that  Has 1 button "button1" and two TextInputs "TX1","TX2" display a certain word in "TX2" when the user types something in "TX1",  For example, The User types "Hello" into "TX1" and i want "Test" to be displayed in "TX2" when the user clicks the button,i also want to be able to add multiple combinations, i have no idea how to make my app do this, perhaps using "Strings" and "If, Else". Thanks

BTW: i do have an alright understanding off android.

Comment: I just really have no idea where to start or i would have posted what i had tried.

Comment: use `onClickListener()` on `button1`, check the text using `getText()` to get `TX1`'s text, then use `setText()` on `TX2`.

Comment: is there a way to add a huge list off combinations to compare/link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding from your question,

you would be having two EditText and one button.

In the onClick event of the button, check the value of editext1, like this

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void OnClick(View v) 
                {
                String val = Editext1.getText();
                if(val.equals("hello")
                {
                      Editext2.setText("Test");
                }
                }
            });
```

Comment: yea something like that

Comment: but how to do check for Hello ?

Comment: Thats it ? Glad to help. But I hope that this is the most basic thing you learn when one starts studying android.

Comment: I have just never needed to use this function thats all.